# Integrating QGIS and ArcSDE for Oracle?

Tags: qgis, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

How can I integrate ArcSDE of Oracle with the QGIS latest version?

I am using ArcGIS 10.4 and QGIS 2.16 version.

Comment: Are you planning on upgrading from QGIS 2.16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make direct connectivity of Oracle database with the QGIS and even can make the edit directly into the Oracle database.

You can follow this tutorial for how to connect your oraacle spatial ( ArcSDE) with the QGIS.

http://www.igismap.com/connect-qgis-oracle-spatial-quantum-gis/

Comment: Oracle Spatial and ArcSDE are *very* different things. It would probably be best if this answer discussed the three (at least) different storage formats and compatibility with QGIS.

Comment: ArcSDE provides capability to make editing with ESRI software. In order to deal with the QGIS you can deal with oracle spatial.

Comment: Please *edit the answe*r to address these issues.  While partially true, your assertion about ArcSDE is sufficiently incomplete as to be misleading..

Comment: I will edit ans, please let me know what m i misleading..

Comment: +Ahsan Mukhtar, The page your are linking to only shows how to connect QGIS to Oracle Spatial. ArcSDE is an extension to Oracle Spatial and not supported in the method you link to, so you will need to remove “(ArcSDE)” from your answer.